# Which array does dstArrayElement refer to in the VkWriteDescriptorSet structure?

Tags: vulkan

Here is the link of VkWriteDescriptorSet structure from vulkan specification:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkWriteDescriptorSet.html

Text pertaining **dstArrayElement**

> dstArrayElement is the starting element in that **ARRAY**. If the descriptor binding identified by dstSet and dstBinding has a descriptor type of VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_INLINE_UNIFORM_BLOCK_EXT then dstArrayElement specifies the starting byte offset within the binding.

I want know which array this statement is refering to?

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much DMGregory,you helpd me again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with a bit context about [`VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding.html) and answer your question afterwards.

---

[`VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding.html) allows to describe not only *one* resource, but an array of resources.

Let's assume that you did not want to use only one texture in a GLSL shader:

```
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D texture;
```

but an array of textures:

```
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D textures[];
```

you'd create a `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding` with multiple texture descriptors, e.g. like follows:

```
VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding dsLayout = {};
dsLayout.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
dsLayout.descriptorCount = 100u;
```

---

With [`VkWriteDescriptorSet`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkWriteDescriptorSet.html) you *write* the actual resource information to the GPU, s.t. your shaders know where they can "find" the resource on the GPU... or maybe more accurate: how they can access a certain resource.

If you wanted to write all `100` texture descriptors at once, you'd set the following data:

```
VkWriteDescriptorSet write = {};
write.dstArrayElement = 0u;
write.descriptorCount = 100u;
```

But if only the 70th texture has changed, you'd like to update only that one with:

```
VkWriteDescriptorSet write = {};
write.dstArrayElement = 69u;
write.descriptorCount = 1u;
```

---

So, **to answer your question**: `dstArrayElement` refers to the array of descriptors defined in `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding`. There will be many cases where `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding` only describes one descriptor (one could also say: an array of length 1), but if you use one `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding` to describe an array of resources, you might not always want to update all of them, but only one (or a few) by specifying an offset into the array of descriptors via `dstArrayElement`.

Btw.: `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding` and `VkWriteDescriptorSet` are linked to the same resource via its `binding` and `dstBinding` members, respectively.

Comment: "VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding allows to describe not only one resource,"do you mean only one type of resource?

Comment: No, I really meant "not only one resource". When I refer to "multiple resources" that can be e.g. "multiple textures" and hence "multiple resources". But it is true that the **resource type** can be set only once for an instance of `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding`.

Comment: Oh，my bad.I thought is was "allows to describe only one resource."Don't know why I accidentally ignore the "not" here